# REST and validation of one field

Tags: rest

I'm no expert in this so please tell me if I'm way off :)

I'm trying to define a REST service that handles accounts.

```
/Accounts/32  (GET to fetch one)
/Accounts     (GET to fetch all)
```

And so on...

However, in the sign up process, before an account is created, I would like to verify a couple of fields, like E-mail and ssn, async before the account is created.

How should I go about doing so? I just want to know if they exist in a combination but I shouldn't get a resource back since it's none of my business. :)

Is it valid to do something like this?

```
/Accounts?ssn=123&email=a@email.com&operation=verifyexistance
```

Thanks

// Johan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting question, for me I would prefer to do the following:

HEAD /accounts?ssn=123&email=a@email.com

if response status code is 200 then the resource exist on the server
if response status code is 404 then the resource not available and you can continue with registration

The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return a message-body in the response.

Answer (score 2):

I like Anas Salman's answer, which suggests the use of `HEAD`.  That's the ideal method.

But I also think that `GET` is perfectly fine.  You are requesting to get information about the resource (the /accounts collection).

```
GET /accounts?ssn=123&email=a@example.org
```

When /accounts sees a request in this format (a `GET` request with an SSN and email address provided), it has enough information to know to respond appropriately with an affirmative or negative.

The addition of an "operation" verb in the query string is the only unRESTFUL part of your example.

Comment: The problem is that the client is unauthorized at the moment and should not get any account back. It's a pre account creation step to ensure the availability of the combination before creating the account.

Comment: @JohanKarlsson I completely understand. In this case, the server would only respond in a "yes" or "no" fashion to indicate if the SSN+email pair was valid (either through the content body or, preferably, HTTP status code).

Comment: The reason for my operator was to be able to control the returning Json so I know what schema to suspect. Is it common practice to return different schemes based on parameters? I'm really new to this. :)

Comment: @JohanKarlsson Yes, that is common practice and it is definitely RESTful to use the query string in that way. Thinking in terms of resources strictly as nouns to be acted upon by a very limited set of verbs (GET, POST, PUT, etc.) is a serious challenge, but its limitations are (arguably) worth it for the consistency it enforces. Using the HEAD method as Anas Salman suggested in his answer would give you the peace of mind of having a separate verb to apply to your /accounts noun, which may feel less arbitrary than 'overloading' GET.